# how to move NSTextField

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I know how to create a NSTextField programmatically in Xcode, but what I want to know is how do I move this around the window?

How do I move an NSTextField from point A to point B?

Answer (score 3):

NSTextField inherits from NSView, which means the way you set its location is with `setFrame:`.

Take a look at the [View Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaViewsGuide/Coordinates/Coordinates.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002978-CH10-SW1) for a full explanation of the concepts of a view's frame & bounds.

Comment: Thanks David that answered my question.  I tried this two ways, but let me explain what I was going for.  I wanted a NSTextField to move around the window when I resize. The best way to do this was to put the NSTextField in the XIB and make an IBOutlet and then code <code>[textField setFrame:...]</code>. Adding the textField as a subview resulted in blurry stuff.